# How to get existing values from the database into the django model field for django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I need help to get existing questions from the field `question_name` into the field `dependent_question` (with dropdown)  from the `Questions` model class. It will help user to select dependent question when they add any new question from django admin panel.

```
# model.py 
class Questions(models.Model):
question_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
question_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
dependent_question = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

It shows you how to achieve that using javascript. I have done this, and it works great.